# FormsAuthentication issue with Custom FormsAuthenticationTicket

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am probably just tired and not seeing what is wrong with this so maybe you folks can give me an idea.

```
 public class AuthTicket : IAuthTicket
{
    #region IAuthTicket Members

    public string CreateAuthenticationTicket(string userName, bool persistent, string userData)
    {
        var formsAuthenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now,
                                                                      DateTime.Now.AddDays(5), persistent, userData,
                                                                      FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(formsAuthenticationTicket);

        return encryptedTicket;
    }

    #endregion
}

// This is injeted in the ctor
string authTicket = _authTicket.CreateAuthenticationTicket(userId.ToString(), true,
                                                                           registerOpenIdUserViewModel.DisplayName);
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,authTicket));


                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

In my controller Action
I have a partial with  @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")
In the Action for LogOff I simply have
FormsAuthentication.SignOut

Well here is the problem, SignOut does not delete the AuthTicket, I still see the cookie and the user cannot logoff.. :) Cool eh?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I just manually forced the cookies to be deleted in my code.

```
Roles.DeleteCookie(  );
```

Comment: LOL... Go figure right. I can do that, but I am too OCD to not figure this one out.

Comment: @Assistant ~ I beat my head on a rock on this one. It was persisting one cookie of the lot, so it was recreating the values of the cookies. Something like that. If you find more information, let me know.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue. In my web.config file i set loginUrl="~/Account/" in the Authentication Section. I did this after reading a bit on what FormsAuthentication.SignOut does ..  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx

Comment: So even if we are not using RedirectToLoginPage etc..., which I never do, that loginUrl looks like it has to be set, even though FormsAuthentication.SignOut does not actually do a redirect. Way to go Microsoft programmers on that one.

Comment: @Assistant ~ I already had that set as well. ... let me double check what you were reading and see if I missed something

Comment: When the SignOut method is called, a redirect to the application's login page is made by calling the Redirect method with the endResponse parameter set to false. The redirect does not take place until the current page has finished executing, so additional code can be run. If the code does not contain an explicit redirect to another page, the user is redirected to the login page configured in the application's configuration file.
Fragemnted thought here... Not really a redirect just returning a view however it is not a view called Index, I am returning a view called SignIn